# How to connect to a database running on VM?

Tags: database, vmware, virtual-machine

I got a question here. Seems a little complicated in my mind. Hope I can make myself clear. :)

1. I have a Win7 system (system A) with a Win7 VM (system B) running on it.
2. System B is connected to a intranet through VPN to log some realtime data into a local sql server database. Internet connection is disabled by administrator so System B is separated from outside.
3. Now System A wants to connect to this database and read these realtime data.

Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of virtual machine are we taking about? (VirtualBox or something else)?

Comment: vmware workstation 9. :) But I can change VM to whichever that works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with **vmware**, but assuming you can use any VM, here's a solution for [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/):

- Setup a network interface on your VM, that's visible to the host
  system only ([reference](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)):

> Host-only networking is another networking mode that was added with
>   version 2.2 of VirtualBox. It can be thought of as a hybrid between
>   the bridged and internal networking modes: as with bridged networking,
>   the virtual machines can talk to each other and the host as if they
>   were connected through a physical ethernet switch. Similarly, as with
>   internal networking however, a physical networking interface need not
>   be present, and the virtual machines cannot talk to the world outside
>   the host since they are not connected to a physical networking
>   interface.

- Configure **port forwarding** on system B ([external_port] -> [host_over_vpn]:[service_port])

Connect to [system_B_ip_over_provided_interface]:[external_port] as if you were connecting to the database directly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to have a try of this solution and get back to this thread! ^_^

Comment: Hi. I just tried the Host-only networking. System B now gets no internet hence is not able to connect to VPN. So I don't think it works. :-(

Comment: You'll need a separate network interface for this purpose (VPN should work on an intranet interface and VM-host communication on another).

Comment: At last I managed to use file based database like SQLite to exchange data. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. Just give correct IPs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. System A and System B are now in different subnets and System B is in an intranet. How can I set the "correct" IPs?